# PHP include depending on account

Tags: php, sql

Im having a issue with my code i am working on. I am trying to get a include loaded depending on the status of the user (if they paid and if they have a invalid email. The NULL value is being pulled form the database however it only sends to the entermail.php

Here is my code does anyone see whats wrong?

```
 function is_premium() {
        $premium_query = mysql_query("SELECT 'authLevel' FROM 'users' WHERE 'fbID' ='".$userId."'");
        $premium = mysql_query($premium_query);
        if ($premium=='1') {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
     }

     function valid_email() {
        $validemail_query = mysql_query("SELECT 'parentEmailOne' FROM 'users' WHERE 'fbID' ='".$userId."'");
        $validemail = mysql_query($validemail_query);
        if ($validemail != 'NULL') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
            }
     }

      if (!empty($session) && is_premium() && valid_email()) {
        include 'indexPremium';

      } else if (!empty($session) && valid_email()) {
        include 'entermail.php';    

     } else if (!empty($session)) {
        include 'indexLoggedIn.php';

    }else{
        include 'indexNotLogged.php'; 
    }
```

Comment: sorry forgot  some of the code:

Comment: You don't need to do `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`. Just do: `return (condition);`

Comment: Oh, and you might want to save the return values somewhere (session?), it would be a waste to do a query _again_ when calling the function for the 2nd (3rd,4th, etc.) time.

Comment: Oh, and you're not even fetching results? Totally missed that: back to the manual you :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually storing the string "NULL" in the database are you? Null is not the same as string "NULL" -- perhaps you want something like:

```
    if (empty($validemail)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Or shorter:

```
return !empty($validemail);
```

Comment: I am Alex I am going to change that now

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `validemail` function:

```
 if (!is_null($validemail)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are not using any parameters. And please use parametrized queries or escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions reference a $userId variable which is neither passed in as a parameter not declared as global. Recommend you declare it as a parameter and pass it in, .e.g

```
function is_premium($userId) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

There are several small things I notice, which can add up to a non-working code. Let me copy one of your functions and work from there:

```
function valid_email() {
  $validemail_query = mysql_query("SELECT 'parentEmailOne' FROM 'users' WHERE 'fbID' ='".$userId."'");       
  $validemail = mysql_query($validemail_query);

  if ($validemail != 'NULL') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The first thing you do is do a query, but you're not selecting field from the database, but rather a value (please not that '' mean values and `` is a field). This would be a better query:

```
"SELECT `parentEmailOne` FROM `users` WHERE `fbID` = '" . $userID . "'"
```

Furthermore, you're using a query twice, which is not the right way to fetch the results. Please use `mysql_fetch_array` to fetch the answer to an array:

```
$validemail = mysql_fetch_array($validemail_query);
```

Then returning would be:

```
return !empty($validemail['parentEmailOne']);
```

Furthermore, please have `$userID` as input for your function (like others mentioned already), since right now it will always be `NULL` (empty). (I mean like this: `function valid_email($userID)`, you then call it like `valid_email(10)` for user with id 10.

*Small update:* You might want to check your if-else-statements, where you repeat a lot of function calls and checks. If you do it like this, you're only executing each function ones but do get the same results.

```
if(!empty($session))
{
    if(valid_email())
    {
        if(is_premium())
            include 'indexPremium';
        else
            include 'entermail.php';
    }
    else
        include 'indexLoggedIn.php'; 
} else
    include 'indexNotLogged.php';
```

This also leads me to believe that there might be an error in your checks, since you want people to go to `entermail.php` when there is no valid email. (If I made no mistakes, the above if-else-statements is what your code will generate for includes, but you might want the following.)

```
if(!empty($session))
{
    if(valid_email())
    {
        if(is_premium())
            include 'indexPremium';
        else
            include 'indexLoggedIn.php';
    }
    else
        include 'entermail.php';
} else
    include 'indexNotLogged.php';
```